# Bootstrap panel text cut-off and overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I'm working on a web app at the moment and I was wondering is there any way to make the text in bootstrap panels cut-off, instead of increasing the height of the panel.

Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/ayfaozbt/

And drag the panel so that its shorter, and so that the text is pushed up/down.
I'm trying to replace that effect with the title (in the example it's Panel-Primary-Overflow) being cut-off instead. So that the end of the title would not be visible but the height of the panel is preserved.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Code:

```
<div id="item{num}-panel" class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="item{num}-header" onclick="$('#item{num}-body').collapse('toggle');">
    <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center">
      <div style="float:left">#52</div>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#item{num}-body" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        Panel-Primary-Overflow.pdf
      </a>
      <div style="float:right">386.5K</div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="item{num}-body" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the **float:left;** use correct bootstrap path and split 3 column like
**col-md-3 col-md-6 col-md-3** for heading.

Comment: I did this and used  {overflow:hidden;    text-overflow:ellipsis;} on the property I wanted to cut off; and it works great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height of the panel heading to be fixed you should set the height in your CSS file. For example:

```
.panel-heading {
  height: 40px
}
```

Start with that and see if its a step in the right direction.

Comment: The same "push down" effect happens with this, although now the pushed down text isn't visible once it goes far enough, as the height stays the same.  Not much closer really..